# Java Streams API - Impose Ordering while collecting with groupingBy()

Tags: java, java-stream, groupingby

I am trying to group the following list of `Foo` objects by `getName()` and count occurrences while ordering by `getNumber()` in ascending order.

*Input:*

```
List<Foo> fooList = List.of(
    new Foo("Alpha", 1.1f),
    new Foo("Delta", 1.2f),
    new Foo("Charlie", 3.1f),
    new Foo("Alpha", 2.1f),
    new Foo("Charlie", 4.1f),
    new Foo("Delta", 2.2f)
);
```

Map Output:

```
{Alpha=2, Delta=2, Charlie=2}
```

My current solution is as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

fooList
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Foo::getNumber))
    .forEach(foo -> {
        int val = map.getOrDefault(foo.getName(), 0);
        map.put(foo.getName(), val + 1); 
    });
```

Is there any better way with `Collectors.groupingBy()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any better way with `Collectors.groupingBy()`?

You need the flavor of [`groupingBy(classifier,mapFactory,downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) which allows to specify a `mapFactory`.

As a *downstream collector*, we need to apply combination of `collectingAndThen()` and `counting()` because the resulting type produced by `counting()` is `Long` and we need to turn it into `Integer`.

```
Map<String, Integer> fooNameByCount = fooList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Foo::getNumber))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Foo::getName,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(),
            Long::intValue)
    ));
```

We can achieve the same result by using a single collector with the following version of [`toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction,mapFactory)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)):

```
Map<String, Integer> fooNameByCount = fooList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Foo::getNumber))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Foo::getName,
        foo -> 1,
        Integer::sum,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

**Also note** that using *collector* is always a preferred way to accumulate the result.

Usage of `forEach()` such cases when you generate the result by the means of `collect()`, `reduce()`, etc. is [*discouraged by the API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects)